# Create new user in rspec controller is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

I am trying to create a new user in my users_controller_spec.rb with the following code. However after I run rspec, no new users have been added. When I put this block in my spec_helper.rb file, on the other hand, the user is created.

```
before(:suite) do
  User.create(name: 'admin admin', email: 'admin@test.com', password: 'testing')
end
```

How can I get this code to work when it is in my users_controller_spec.rb?

I am using rspec, mongoid, and rails 3.2.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `before :suite` to prepare db records.

In this case, if you have more than one example in this context, the second one can not see the data because it was cleaned after first example run.

To fix, simply change `before :suite` to `before`, which defaults to `before :each`.

Comment: Just a question: What is run first, before(:suite) in spec_helper.rb or before(:suite) in the spec file that is being tested?

Comment: Jeremy, I think the ones in configuration should be run at first.